# Are Pokemon from eggs still useful at lvl 30?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm wondering if once you're lvl 30, are Pokemon from eggs still useful for fights as they are only lvl 20 (candies are, but the Pokemon itself) ?

Comment: At the very least, candies. At best it could be a high IV pokemon which you can power up.

Answer (score 8):

Basically you won't get better Pokémon after reaching level 20 due to this:

```
  TemplateId: "PLAYER_LEVEL_SETTINGS"
  PlayerLevel {
    RankNum: (...)
    RequiredExp: (...)
    CpMultiplier: (...)
    MaxEggPlayerLevel: 20
    MaxEncounterPlayerLevel: 30
  }
```

But(!):

- Rare Pokémon
- Pokémon with neat values ([this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281226/at-what-level-iv-perfection-should-we-power-our-pokemon?noredirect=1#comment395533_281226) for example)
- Candy
- More Candy
- Filling your Pokédex
- Even more Candy

So yes, hatching eggs is still useful until you completed your Pokédex and powered up everything. Especially collecting (and using) Candy will be a pain in higher levels, since the power up costs will be pretty high.

Comment: Neat values ? so if they have good values is it worth it to power them up ? [at what level iv perfection should we power our pokemon?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281226/at-what-level-iv-perfection-should-we-power-our-pokemon?noredirect=1#comment395533_281226)

Comment: @ElChapo Sure. My answer there would still count here. :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, define *useful*.

It depends on you, if you want to *catch'em all* or if you want the strongest one. Or maybe you want to evolve Pokemon.

- Evolve: eggs are useful. It gives you a good amount of candy. See: [How many candies do you get for every 2k, 5k, and 10k egg?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276005/how-many-candies-do-you-get-for-every-2k-5k-and-10k-egg)
- Strongest: it depends on when did you get the egg, not when hatched.
- Catch'em all: You can get 73 pokemon by egg

Answer (score 0):

As long as you get a rare pokemon that you or many other people do not have , sure it is.

Answer (score -1):

As dly said it's about candies, filling pokedex and high IVs, but on higher levels the thing that really matters is IVs, because you probably will have tons of candies and filled pokedex(well, may be without legendaries). And you will look for pokemon with 90%+ or 95%+ IVs(attack, defense and HP are almost 15) which are much more likely obtained from eggs.
90%+ IVs pokemon are a really rare thing to catch.

Comment: What source do you have that higher IVs are more likely from eggs?